# What is Best Address to use to receive multiple payments?

Tags: wallet

I plan on attaching my Bitcoin Addresse to a program that will pay me multiple times. I plan on setting it and using only one. So which address is the best to use, the one that starts with BC or the number 1?

My fear is that if I put the one BTC address that keeps changing onto the program, then I may not receive multiple payments. Because the address wouldn't be good.

Share Edit Flag

Answer (score 1):

All those addresses have the same structure (a public key hash) and are used the same way.

The difference is, `bc1` addresses keep transaction signatures in a separate place in the blockchain than `1` addresses. That is, there's a **fee discount** when you spend from `bc1` addresses. Without any doubts, the newer `bc1` addresses are superior.

The reason `1` addresses are still in use is, legacy codebases that aren't updated for `bc1` compatibility. Use `bc1` whenever possible.

Comment: So the BC1 will never change? I plan on leaving it for everyone on my platform, to pay me continuously. So once I set, I dont have to worry?

Comment: No, all addresses change, but you can still pay to the previous address without any doubt. You'll always receive it